# Can't access uploaded files or files written by php

Tags: php, apache, unix

I'm having a problem with my server at work, it's not letting me access any files via FTP that were uploaded or created by PHP, like log files and user uploads. I CAN access them via HTTP.

Server - Apache/1.3.41 (Unix)

This is a big problem for me, and I feel like it must be some server configuration because this doesn't happen elsewhere. I am going to call our "server guy" and try to get him to correct this, but first I wanted to see if anyone had any clues about what might be going on before I do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, it's probably because when you upload files, the web server itself is writing those file to the disk, hence the files end up with the web-server's user permissions which are different from yours. If you need to be able to modify those files, have your php app chown() them to a group you have access to and chmod() them accourdingly.

Comment: Does it matter that I can manually change permissions through my FTP client and still cannot access the files?
Does it make a difference that I've only had this problem on this particular server and nowhere else?
I should have all possible permissions already, but I got an "Operation not permitted" warning when I attempted to chown() the directory/files.
Another problem is that there are several apps, some third party, that are writing files and uploading files, all over the place.

Is it at all possible that this is something that can be fixed by our server guy?

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like a job for your server guy. If he's no help try ServerFault

Comment: Coming back to this (my first post I believe) several months later - the only solution was to enable ssh access and turn it off when we were done, usually after the project has been live for a few weeks. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a permissions issue; the user ftp is running as doesn't have permission to access the files that were created by the php/web user.